# Eclipse OS X shortcut for Debug History

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Is there a quick way to get to the Debug History in eclipse on OS X by just using the keyboard?

On Windows you can do

<kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>Number</kbd>

to invoke the nth entry from the history or simply

<kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd>

to invoke the last entry (e.g. last test).

What possiblities are there on OS X?

Answer (score 3):

You were using **mnemonics** in Windows. However, Mac OS X doesn't support mnemonics and you can't do it like in Windows or Linux.

[This link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=399554) would help you understand the problem. According to [Mac OS UI guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html), **mnemonics violate the principles of OS X Human Interface Guidelines.**

So the most handy way to achieve your goal is to just hit the `Debug` button on the toolbar, or expand its popup and select the run configuration what you want to run. You can re-run the last debug by `Cmd+F11`.

Comment: Thanks for this anwser. I will leave this question open in the hope that the eclipse community will provide us with a possiblity to create a short cut for the debug history. Once this has been done I will accept the answer.